# A continuity result

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

Suppose (i) $f:R^n_+\to R$ and (ii) $f(x)=f(\alpha x)$, for all $\alpha>0$ and (iii) For any $x,y\in R^n_+$, if $x_n\to x^*$,  $y_n\to x^{*}$, we have   $\lim f(x_n)=\lim f(y_n)$.

Could I  claim that

$$f(x)=\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} f(\alpha x)= \lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} f(\alpha y)=f(y) $$

for all $x,y\in R^n_+$?

My concern is about the first part, when do we have $f(x)=\lim_{\alpha \to 0} f(\alpha x)$?

Comment: Could you tell what $R^{n}_{+}$ means?

Comment: Hi, it means $\{x\in R^n| x_i\geq 0, i=1,...,n\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have $f(x)=\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0^+} f(\alpha x)$ (or even $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0} f(\alpha x)$), because $f(x)=f(\alpha x) \ \ \ \forall \alpha>0$ and because $\alpha< 0$ is not allowed.

Edit: I did not realise that the set $R^n_+$ was closed. However, generally it would have been taken to be open, so you should check whether the set $R^n_+$ is really meant to be the one you defined.

Yes, you can claim that
$f(x)=\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} f(\alpha x)= \lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} f(\alpha y)=f(y)$

However I would prefer to write it in the sequential form thus (since the information you are given is in terms of sequences, not as limits of real functions):
With $x_i = \frac1i\cdot x$ and $y_i=\textbf 0$, you have $x_i\to \textbf 0$ and $y_i\to \textbf 0$.
This implies that $\lim f(\frac1i\cdot x) = \lim f(\textbf 0)=f(\textbf 0)$.
But $\lim f(\frac1i\cdot x)=\lim f(x) = f(x)$ since $f(\frac1i\cdot x)= f(x)$.
Thus for all $x$ and $y$, $f(x)=f(\textbf 0)=f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks.  so we can conclude that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in R_n^+$? Why would $\textbf{0}$ not in $R_+^n?$

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, you are right. You can definitely claim that. I messed up the meaning of $R^n_+$ again.

Comment: Oh, I think $\textbf{0}$ is not in my domain...I mean $f$ is defined to rule out   $\textbf{0}$, as you said, in this case, the result does not hold?

Comment: Okay, in that case it depends whether you allow $x^*$ to be equal to $\textbf 0$ or not; most probably you don't, and then the result does not hold.